# Creating a visualizer Unity3d

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, visualizer

I have been trying to find some things online about how to make your own visualizer that responds to sound, But so far I only could find tutorials for on a mac.

I also found some premade visualizer but prefer not to spend 50$ on a asset for it
 [theasset](http://u3d.as/content/altered-reality-entertainment/visualizer-studio/2dq)

I was wondering of somebody could maybe tell me how to basicly code a particle system to respond to sound interactions such as certain frequency's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a nice tutorial here: http://www.41post.com/4776/programming/unity-making-a-simple-audio-visualization.
It is able to get different frequencies from the sounds and do something accordingly. You can try and change the variables of the particle with it.

<s>Another thing I found is a project which analyses the spectrum of sound. You can [download it here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7155207/AudioReactWIN.zip).</s>

I also found [this tutorial](http://unity3dtutorial.com/unity-3d-tutorials/audio-based-procedural-levelgeneration-manipulation-in-unity-3/) which generates a level based on the sound.

**These links no longer works**

Try them out and let us know what you thought of them and if they helped! Good luck.

Comment: The first link I found myself already couldnt seem to get it working with a particle system. The third thing you noted seems intresting. gonna try it out straight away ! :)

Comment: Also, you can try out this site and ask your questions there: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ They seem to get more responses then on Stackoverflow, unless it's code related.

Comment: It is not totaly working the way i want but its realy close to it , ill check gamedev for some more specific info about the subject aswel ^^